# Retrieving the highest number in an array recursively in C#?

Tags: c#, recursion

How can I retrieve the highest number in an array recursively in C#?

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: What's the problem? Create a function that loops recursively through an array, and create a max value variable. If the current value in the current position in the array is bigger than the current max value, max value = current element. Easy as that.

Comment: More information is needed if you want a pertinent answer.

Comment: If this is homework tag it with Homework. Usually many in this forum are hesitant to answer these kind of homework questions unless you tag it as homework. You would atleast be guided with some hints.

Comment: Is this a homework question? I would think recursion would be a bad way to find a maximum value of an array. You could easily run into stack overflows. Otherwise, just use a simple loop or LINQ: myarray.Max()

Answer (score 8):

Right now you're probably thinking that we're mean for not giving you the answer -- and I admit that I have the answer written down and part of me wants to give it to you, even.

Programming is all about finding the solutions to problems yourself. When you're hired as a programmer, you may have other people to lean on, but they've all got their own problems, and you'll need to be able to pull your own weight.

Recursion (in an oversimplifed answer) means to call the same operation over and over until the result is produced.  That means you need in every recursive operation, you need to know (at least) two things:

1. What you're looking for
2. What you've found so far

The 'What you're looking for' is the termination condition.  Once you find that, all work can stop and you can go home.

The 'what you've found so far' is how you know what've you've checked so you don't retread old ground.

So what do you need to know in order to find the highest value in an array recursively?

1. The contents of the Array.
2. The highest number you've found so far.
3. Have you already looked at this part of the Array? (Why look through it again?)

That would produce a method signature that looks like:

```
public int GetHighestNumber(int[] array, int highestNumberFound, int lastIndexChecked);
```

Once you're inside the array, you've got to do the following:

1. Iterate through the array
2. Stop when you find a value that is higher than the `highestNumberFound`
3. Call `GetHighestNumber` again with the new `highestNumberFound` and `lastIndexChecked` updated.
4. When there are no more 'higher' numbers, then return the highest number found.

---

I realize it sounds trite, but learning this stuff *on your own* will make you a better programmer.

If you want to be a professional programmer, you have got to learn this stuff on your own.

If you don't want to be a professional programmer, then drop the course and do something you love.

Answer (score 4):

Here's just a hint (taking `int[]` as an example):

```
public int FindMax(int[] array, int indexSoFar, int maxSoFar)
```

Think about:

- The start conditions
- The termination conditions
- How you move through the array recursively

Answer (score 0):

Reason of EDIT: Didnt want to spoil the answere.
Greetings.